# Rspec/Capybara cant find my model when trying to use "should_not change"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I am trying to verify that the validators are working correctly on my model, and for that I am using Rspec and Capybara. Here is my code.

```
describe "#when registering" do
    before { visit new_record_path } 
        describe "#with invalid information" do
            describe "#should not modify database" do
                subject { -> { click_button submit } }
                    it { should_not change(Pet, :count) }
                    it { should_not change(Owner, :count) }
                end
            end
     end
end
```

When I run the specs, i get an error: "undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class"

What could be causing rspec to think my model is nil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not test your validations with a feature/acceptance test, it should be with a model test. Then for each form you could test an error is raised if something is invalid instead of testing every error through acceptance tests. For each model it should be something like so:

```
describe Pet do
  describe "validations" do
    # These can echo any model validation
    it "is invalid if attribute is not present" do
      Pet.new(:attribute => "Invalid Item").should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

or with Factory Girl:

```
describe Pet do
  describe "validations" do
    it "is invalid if attribute is not present" do
      build(:pet, :attribute => "Invalid Item").should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Then in an acceptance test you can have something like:

```
  it "displays an error if validation fails" do
     visit new_pet_path

     #Something to make the form submission fail, not everything
     fill_in("Attribute", :with => "")
     click_button("Create Pet")

     page.should have_content("can't be blank")
     current_path.should == pets_path
   end
```

This will help to keep your acceptance tests light and test the validations in the model where it belongs. Hope this helps!